# Switch-Case block not executing as intended?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

In the following code snippet, what I intend is on every timer tick event, it should fall in 'next' case of the switch statement.
However, as I Run, it goes through Odd cases first and then even cases?

What mistake I am making?

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        switch (SCROLL_SCREEN_NO)
        {
            case 0: 
                    SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 1;
                    break;

            case 1: label1.Text = "Param1";
                    label2.Text = "1234";
                    SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 2;
                    break;

            case 2: label1.Text = "Param2";
                    label2.Text = "5678";
                    SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 3;
                    break;

            case 3: label1.Text = "Param3";
                    label2.Text = "9012";
                    SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 0;
                    break;

            case 4: label1.Text = "Param4";
                    label2.Text = "0";
                    SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 5;
                    break;

            case 5: label1.Text = "Param5";
                    label2.Text = "02";
                    SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 0;
                    break;

            default: { break; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not debugging properly and not coding relevant samples. Switch goes  through the elements as they are shown. DUmping your code at us is not goingto debug it.

Comment: What is your tick count? I doubt that the timer ticks before the SCROLL_SCREEN_NO is set for the next execution.

Comment: case 3 looks wrong it's setting it back 0

Comment: @ConradFrix sorry for typo-err ...you pointed right , case 3 : SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = 4;

Comment: Just write the `SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = (SCROLL_SCREEN_NO+1) % 5;` after the switch body

Comment: @bit tick count is 1000. I dont think setting variable takes that long.

Comment: try with a variable and intialize it with 0, increment it in every call.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo did you mean I should not set variable SCROLL_SCREEN_NO in case and should set outside switch as you suggested?

Comment: @Dev I tried that , but didn't help!

Comment: @jrk007 I put my mean for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is really mistakable, try this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] L1Keys = new string[]{"Param1", "Param2","Param3","Param4","Param5"};
   string[] L2Keys = new string[]{"1234", "5678","9012","0","02"};
   label1.Text = L1Keys[SCROLL_SCREEN_NO];
   label2.Text = L2Keys[SCROLL_SCREEN_NO];

   if(SCROLL_SCREEN_NO >=0 && SCROLL_SCREEN_NO<=4)
       SCROLL_SCREEN_NO = (SCROLL_SCREEN_NO+1) % 5;
}
```

Comment: did not help. running though Param3 ,Param5 and Param1 only.

Comment: That's coincidence even I edited and tested with the same change. but still it is running through Param3,Param5,Param1,Param2,Param4

Comment: the other thing in code code is wrong, I test it and it completely works

Comment: you are right!...there was mistake in other part. Actually , by mistake, there were two event handlers running for the timer1. One event handler created by IDE by double clicking (unintentional) and other written in code as -      timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);      Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK.
Are you using SCROLL_SCREEN_NO outside of this timer tick event?
If so then please look at the code again that used SCROLL_SCREEN_NO.

Comment: SCROLL_SCREEN_NO is only initialized outside. Rest everything is done in timer1_tick only.